# how to call Function of parent form from child form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an application which consists of 2 forms, parent and child.
In parent form I have a frame. If button 1 of parent form is clicked then child form will open inside the frame. Now what I need is when button 2 of child form is clicked then it should call the `Button2_click` of the parent form.
Here is my parent form code:

```
public  void MethodToExecute() //call this method
{
    UPCCharges.Update();
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["CCost"] != null)
    {
        TxtCCost.Text = Session["CCost"].ToString();
    }

    DivCCharges.Visible = false;
    IFMCCharge.Visible = false;
}
```

and this is Form 2 code:

```
protected void dgCFrom_ItemCommand(Object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    UPCFromGrid.Update();
    for (int vLoop2 = 0; vLoop2 < gvInner1.Items.Count; vLoop2++)
    {
        if (TxtTotalCFrom1 != null && TxtTotalCFrom2 != null)
        {
            TextBox TxtTotalCFrom = (TextBox)dgCFrom.Items[vLoop].FindControl("TxtTotalCFrom");
            TextBox TxtTotalCYeild = (TextBox)dgCFrom.Items[vLoop].FindControl("TxtTotalCYeild");

            Session["CCost"] = (mobjGenlib.ConvertDecimal(TxtTotalCFrom1.Text) + mobjGenlib.ConvertDecimal(TxtTotalCFrom2.Text)).ToString();
            Session["CYeild"] = (mobjGenlib.ConvertDecimal(TxtRecoveryOrigin.Text) - mobjGenlib.ConvertDecimal(TxtTotalCFrom.Text)).ToString();
            Session["CName"] = dgCFrom.Items[vLoop].Cells[1].Text;
            Session["CJobID"] = HBLGeneralID;

        }
    }
}
FrmMasterSimulationChartNewUF frm = new FrmMasterSimulationChartNewUF();
frm.MethodToExecute();
}
```

The error I am getting is:

When keeping break point in the main form function `MethodtoExecute` getting as Object reference not set to null. But from form1 if execute it was working with no error.

Can anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: You mean you're using html frames? What year is this?

Comment: I am Using IFrame.But if my guess is correct  i think iframe does not play a role in calling the Parent form function from the button click of the child form.

Comment: Don't do that.. Iframes should be used only for the scenarios when you don't have any control over the "child" stuff.. For instance when you have a very basic site and want to include a 3rd party guest book.. Or when you use Facebook api and similar situations. There's no way you can manipulate "parent" from iframe on the server-side.. Maybe some hacky javascript/ajax, but it's a very ugly and error-prone way of doing things.

Comment: You wanna call a method from Master page in Content page, right?

Comment: Well said  i understood .but I am in a situation to use as i described above since my customer is decided go in such a way so no other go for me.if you don't mind and If it is possible please orient me.

Comment: @Aria yes most probably

Answer (score 1):

You should reference to master page

so add something like this line to your Contetnt page design:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.master" %>
```

and try something like this:

```
 var master = Master as SiteMaster;
    SiteMaster mm = new SiteMaster();
    mm.MethodToExecute();
    master.MethodToExecute();
```

Let me know the feedback.

Comment: Will Try your solution and get back to you as soon as possible

Comment: i am getting error in the word master...and also i already  tried in the way FrmMasterSimulationChartNewUF frm = new FrmMasterSimulationChartNewUF();
                if (frm != null)
                {
                    frm.MethodToExecute();
                }    but as described above get object referen error in that function

Comment: Ok see my edited answer. I just tested it, it works like a charm !

Comment: i am calling content page from another content

Comment: You said you want call a method from Master in content page right?

Comment: hi ....most probably but its from content to content...sorry if i had confused you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72050/discussion-between-appdev-and-aria).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming here your "child" form is actually inside an iframe of the "parent" Form, and that both of these pages, are hosted on the same application and domain.

You can attach a javascript click event to Button2 of the child form to then invoke the click event of Button2 on the parent form using parent.document

E.g.

```
<button id="Button2" onclick="parent.document.getElementById('Button2').click();return false;">Child button 2</button>
```

Just beware of the actual ID values of your buttons , as they maybe changed due to UpdatePanels etc.